# How to redirect/rewrite all /wp-login requests

Tags: wp-admin, login, url-rewriting

Is there any simple way to have wordpress, php or apache rewrite all urls which involve `/wp-admin` to `/admin`?

I have added this entry to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^admin /wp-login.php [L]
```

However although `domain.com/admin` will correctly show the login page all pages after you login show the URL as `/wp-admin` which I want to always show `/admin`.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I rename the wp-admin folder?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106/can-i-rename-the-wp-admin-folder)

Comment: @Rarst -- I saw that one but I figured my question was more targeted and might allow someone to answer the question as it seems like this should somehow be possible in a round about way...

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding something your question is currently worded as **exactly** about changing `wp-admin` to `admin`, which is not possible according to answers on that other question. If you want to achieve something else please write it out a bit?..

Comment: @Rarst -- Are you sure there is no php, apache or wordpress way to get all backend links which point to /wp-admin to point to a different directory? I know that through mod-rewrite once can create an alias folder and define all content for that folder to be pulled from a different location. Thus I figured there must be some way to force wordpress to write those urls instead of /wp-admin... thats the question I am after. Do you still suggest the rewrite?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer you question as a apache URL layout configuration via [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (the apache module that handles URL rewriting), this could be helpful:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /wp-admin/$1 [QSA,L]
```

(untested configuration directive, check the docs in case this does errors)

This will basically translate any request to /admin/... into /wp-admin/... .

If that's the only thing you would like to know, I must admit that this is slightly off-topic for worpdress@se as this is acutally a question how to configure the apache webserver. A better place might be [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/about).

---

Keep in mind that this only rewrites the URLs that get requested. Wordpress would know nothing about this and it does still output links to /wp-admin/ on the admin then. There is a hook for any admin URL that you might want to rewrite then as well:

```
return apply_filters('admin_url', $url, $path, $blog_id);
```

You would need to replace the `domain/wp-admin/` part with `domain/admin/` with a filter on your own.

Comment: @hakre -- Thank you, this is basically exactly what I was looking for. The area I am less familiar with is the apply_filters aspect. I am assuming this gets placed into the functions.php file towards the top correct? Could you possibly provide a example of this wordpress line which would automativcally modify all /wp-admin/(.*) request to /admin/(.*)

Comment: It's a bit more complex, as it needs to do some additional settings as well. I've created a must-use plugin for reference: https://gist.github.com/701245#file_change_admin_url.php

Comment: @hakre -- I have tried the code you posted on github but this did not seem to work for me. For some strange reason I was not even able to see the plugin. What I did notice is that you said to place it in the mu-plugins folder but I am assuming placing it in your regular plugins folder (without mu in place) will work as well (even if you changed the name of the plugin folder (defined through the wp-config file)?

Comment: If created and placed correctly into the must use plugin folder, you should be able to see the filename listed unter the "Must Use" tab under Plugins: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2h4mclc&s=7 - Otherwise I would not wonder about that it is not working. First get it there. Don't forget to configure the .htaccess file as well.

Comment: @Rarst -- I just revisited this again and noticed that it was actually me that was doing things wrong. Once I placed the code into mu-plugins it worked! Two follow up questions please... how can I modify your code so that I can just write it into my functions.php file instead? The next question is... how can I make all requests to /wp-admin, /wp-admin/index.php and /wp-login.php give a 404 error? My goal is to make it so that only /admin or /admin/index.php gives a user a login page and all others provide an error

Comment: You can try to put the file next to your function.php file and include it on top of your function.php file. But this might not work because it might be already too late then to reconfigure cookies. So you have been warned :) -

Comment: For the 404 issue, please ask over at serverfault how you can do this configuration with your webserver.

Comment: Where exactly to you put the line "
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /wp-admin/$1 [QSA,L]" ???

Comment: Where should i put the code return apply_filters('admin_url', $url, $path, $blog_id);

Comment: @santosh: Hook into the filter inside some (plugin) code on your own. It's just the fitting filter, used as any other filter :)

Answer (score 5):

hakre.... Great answer... now with the latest version of wordpress having a separate network admin I used your solution and added in the part to properly rewrite the "Network Admin" links in the same way...

```
    /**
     * Change Admin URL
     * 
     * Copyright (C) 2010  hakre <http://hakre.wordpress.com/>
     * 
     * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
     * it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as
     * published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the
     * License, or (at your option) any later version.
     * 
     * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
     * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
     * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
     * GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
     * 
     * You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
     * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
     * 
     * USAGE: 
     * 
     * Copy the file into  wp-content/mu-plugins  directory and add the 
     * following RewriteRule to your apache configuration or .htaccess:
     * 
     *  RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ wp-admin/$1 [QSA,L]
     * 
     * It will rewrite the wordpress admin-URL 
     *  
     *   from: http://example.com/wp-admin/ ...
     *   to  : http://example.com/admin/ ...
     * 
     * @author hakre <http://hakre.wordpress.com>
     * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/how-to-redirect-rewrite-all-wp-login-requests/4063
     * @todo mod_rewrite_rules - filter to insert into .htacces on plugin activation
     * 
     */
    /** Updated version my Mark Figueredo, <http://gruvii.com/> **/
    return ChangeAdminUrlPlugin::bootstrap();

    class ChangeAdminUrlPlugin {
     private $renameFrom = 'wp-admin';
     private $renameTo = 'admin';
     static $instance;
     static public function bootstrap() {
      null === self::$instance
       && self::$instance = new self()
       ;
      return self::$instance;
     }
     private function setCookiePath() {
      defined('SITECOOKIEPATH') || define('SITECOOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option('siteurl') . '/' ) );
      defined('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH') || define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . $this->renameTo);
     }
     public function __construct() {
      $this->setCookiePath();
      add_action('init', array($this, 'init')) ;
     }
     public function init() {
      add_filter('admin_url', array($this, 'admin_url'), 10, 3);
      add_filter('network_admin_url', array($this, 'network_admin_url'), 10, 3);//Added by Mark Figueredo, <http://gruvii.com/>
     }
     public function admin_url($url, $path, $blog_id) {
      $renameFrom = $this->renameFrom;
      $renameTo = $this->renameTo;
      $scheme = 'admin';
      $find = get_site_url($blog_id, $renameFrom.'/', $scheme);
      $replace = get_site_url($blog_id, $renameTo.'/', $scheme);
      (0 === strpos($url, $find))
       && $url = $replace.substr($url, strlen($find))
       ;
      return $url;
     }
// Added by Mark Figueredo, <http://gruvii.com/> 
     public function network_admin_url($url, $path) {
      $renameFrom = $this->renameFrom;
      $renameTo = $this->renameTo;
      $scheme = 'admin';
      $find = network_site_url($renameFrom.'/', $scheme);
      $replace = network_site_url($renameTo.'/', $scheme);
      (0 === strpos($url, $find))
       && $url = $replace.substr($url, strlen($find))
       ;
      return $url;
     }
    }
```

Comment: did you experience any issues or problems with this code? I was noticing pages taking longer to load on the admin area and some plugins where operating a bit strange...

Comment: Hello ! Just now I found this post when searching for a solution to replace ' wp- '. Could any one tell me if there is any problem using this code as @Netcontrucor.com said?

Thanks !

Comment: It seems your code does not work if wordpress is installed on a subdomain as it seems to try to redirect to the root domain name. Can you confirm this and if so please update this code? Thanks, CH

Comment: Please add urls of the subdomains etc. otherwise it's hard to say // I can imagine that cookies aren't working for changing domains with the current code properly.

Comment: Hey, where exactly do I put the RewriteRule inside of htaccess with relation to the other wordpress rules?... DOes it matter?

Comment: BTW... I also used a symlink from admin -> wp-admin

Comment: Can you add the symlink .htaccess lines to the answer for reference? Perhaps you have something like this requiring adding the `-l` line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412955/htaccess-config-with-symbolic-links-and-index-files-not-working-as-expected ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous solutions. I found the missing css and script files.

the fix is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

# Fix using the previous answer. 
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ wp-admin/$1 [QSA,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]

#Fix to load css js image files for multi site admin urls. 
#old code RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.(php|css|js|png|jpg|gif))$ $1 [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks, have you experience any issues or limitations using this approach?

Comment: I would imagine any plugins that don't abide by WP standards will not work.