# Changing the 'wp-admin' URL to whatever I want

Tags: wp-admin

Is there a plugin that allows me to change the url of domain.com/**wp-admin** to domain.com/**whatever-iwant** ? Curious if there is an easy solution to this by now.

Comment: Please see as well: How to redirect/rewrite all /wp-login requests - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/how-to-redirect-rewrite-all-wp-login-requests/4063

Answer (score 12):

If you're looking for a way to physically move the wp-admin folder to another location, that is indeed problematic. That's why there is not an easy solution available. Not that it isn't just easy, it is even the opposite. The directory name "wp-admin" is hardcoded deeply into wordpress. This is **by design**, so wordpress actively prevents to allow a change here.

Naturally you can solve this by hacking core and/or by reconfiguring the directory layout within your file-system and the server configuration in addition with a plugin.

An example has been given in [***How to redirect/rewrite all /wp-login requests***](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/how-to-redirect-rewrite-all-wp-login-requests/4063#4063), an [example plugin is available as well](https://gist.github.com/701245). You must be able to reconfigure apache for that example.

#### Update:

This is another related question: [***Can I rename the wp-admin folder?***](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106/can-i-rename-the-wp-admin-folder) with a detailed answer by mike.