# Manually Moving Posts/Pages/Comments/Tags from WPMU to WP3.0

Tags: multisite

Seems when I import the WPMU's XML file into the WP 3.0 install, I lose a ton of Pages/Posts/Categories. I am now leaning towards just manually moving over the tables from WPMU to WP3.0. Yet, when I do a dump of just wp_posts I get a sql error - making me think moving the db tables from WPMU to WP3.0 will be more complex.

Any help would be appreciated in figuring out how to correctly move over these tables so I don't have to do the XML export/import all day with no results.

Comment: if you look at my questions, each one has had an accepted answer.

Comment: ping: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4789/changing-the-wp-admin-url-to-whatever-i-want

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure from your description if you have active WPMU install or only XML export from it?

From googling around upgrading active WPMU install to 3.x should be more or less robust:

- [Best way to migrate WPMU 2.9.2 sites to a fresh WP3.0.1 install?](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/best-way-to-migrate-wpmu-292-sites-to-a-fresh-wp301-install)
- [Upgrading from WPMU to WP 3.0](http://wpmututorials.com/how-to/upgrading-from-wpmu-to-wp-3-0/)

IF you are not sure about upgrading, I'd try to re-create and upgrade install on test installation and possibly use its export (already from 3.x multisite) to import on production.