# How to change "wp-admin" to something else without search-replacing the core?

Tags: wp-admin, url-rewriting, htaccess, security

for example: foobar.com/wp/edit instead of foobar.com/wp/wp-admin

How would I do that?

I've tried using this in htaccess but it won't work:

```
##### ABOVE THIS POINT IS ALREADY INSERTED BY WORD PRESS
##### Admin Base Rewrite #####
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !sercretword
RewriteRule .*\.php [F,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !secretword
RewriteRule ^secret_room/(.*) wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING}&secretword [L]
##### End Admin Base Rewrite #####
##### BELOW THIS POINT IS ALREADY INSERTED BY WORD PRESS
```

It was created by Michi Kono. I just can't get it to work though.

I'm not trying to be more secure by obscurity... Its more for functionality. My site will be world editable (kind of like a wiki) but only for registered users. They will go to "/edit" instead of "/wp-admin" to edit or add content.

Thanks for the help!

NOTE: I *did* see this question: [Can I rename the wp-admin folder?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106/can-i-rename-the-wp-admin-folder)
But that doesn't have an answer.

NOTE: Stealth Admin plugin doesn't seem to do the trick either.

NOTE: I tried this solution: [How to redirect/rewrite all /wp-login requests](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/how-to-redirect-rewrite-all-wp-login-requests/4063#4063)
But I'm not sure where in the htaccess file to place the rewrite rule with respect to the wordpress rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) plugin, it's great for exactly that.

**EDIT**

You could also for example setup a subdomain that makes a transparent redirect, as in : http://admin.mywebsite.com/ which you would redirect to your wp-admin/ folder. But then I think people would still see the wp-admin/ in all the links (on hover for ex).

Comment: So how would I use it to make /wp/edit be the admin path instead of /wp/wp-admin ? For example, if i'm gunna edit posts, the path would be /wp/edit/post.php instead of /wp/wp-admin/post.php.

Comment: Checkout the [screenshots](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/screenshots/) of the plugins page. You simply put in the old path and the new path you want to replace it with.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. This plugin can make it so that /wp/edit can redirect to /wp/wp-admin, and the user will see "/wp/wp-admin" in the address bar. What I really want is for the address bar to always show "/wp/edit" at all times, not just redirect to /wp/wp-admin. Get what I mean?

Comment: Yes guess I see, so it's not really "functionality" you want but "esthetic"? It's because you don't want people to see the "wp" prefix or something? In that case you could for example setup a subdomain that makes a transparent redirect, as in : `http://admin.mywebsite.com/` which you would redirect to your `wp-admin/` folder. But then I think people would still see the `wp-admin/` in all the links (on hover for ex).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. That could work. I'm creating a map of spots, and anyone can submit or edit spots, so "edit" or "edit-spots" or even "dashboard" seems more friendly and relevant than "wp-admin" edit.foobar.com seems nice though. I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: Hey mike23, add that subdomain as an answer so I might accept it if I use that solution.

Comment: @truskt, ok done.

Comment: @trusktr or you can take completely different way and make it possible to add / edit map spots from the front end. Then the permalinks and the easthetics are the easier part.

Comment: That is very true, I'm actually working on that!... It is just a little more complicated though because I have to figure out how to implement all the plugin features on the front-end (features that plugins add to the backend editing screen)... But its definitely doable. Another problem with that is that i might have to edit the front-end templates a each time a plugin has updates.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your htaccess place the code literally on the first line before any other comments or code added by wordpress or other plugins.

As Jan mentioned rewriting consists of two parts. So beside .htaccess you need to change the admin_url filter

```
function custom_admin_url($path) { 
    return str_replace('wp-admin', 'dashboard', $path); 
}
add_filter('admin_url', 'custom_admin_url');
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing a URL always consists of two parts: changing the code that accepts the URLs (to make sure you get something when you go to `example.com/edit`), and changing the URLs that the code outputs in the HTML (so a link to `wp-admin/` will be written as `edit/`).

The first part is the easy part, and you can do it with Apache rewrite rules. This way you make make a request for `example.com/edit` look like it was for `example.com/wp-admin`.

The second part is the hard part, and indeed requires a global search-and-replace, because it is "hard-coded" all over the place. The discussions and Trac tickets [Mike linked to in his answer to the older question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106/can-i-rename-the-wp-admin-folder/126#126) indicate that the core developers currently have no plans to change this, because they do not see the benefit. Indeed, your use case could also be handled in a way that does not require you to use `wp-admin` (moving everything to the front-end).