# Front-End Post Submission

Tags: posts, front-end

I am trying to add a form where users can submit post from front-end.

I am Following this tutorial:
http:// wpshout.com/wordpress-submit-posts-from-frontend/

What I am doing is adding [this code](http://new2wp.com/labs/downloads/New_Post_Forn_by-Jared_New2WP.txt) to one of my page-template. The form shows up alright but when I click on the submit button it gives me "**Page not found error**"

Many of the commenter saying it is not working.
Can anyone point me to the right direction? Is the code incomplete?has flaws? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Towfiq I.

Comment: Can you explain your use-case?  There are many options but some are not ones to suggest for all use cases.

Comment: fix your question title from Fron-End to Frontend or Front-End.

Comment: Check out this very cool and easy to follow tutorial on how to post from the front end (including photo galleries and custom fields!!).
[vudu.me/postreview](http://vudu.me/postreview)

Comment: You can use the code snippets from this tutorial to create a simple WP Front End Posting plugin: [http://www.cozmoslabs.com/5528-wordpress-post-from-front-end/](http://www.cozmoslabs.com/5528-wordpress-post-from-front-end/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<?php $postTitle = $_POST['post_title'];
$post = $_POST['post'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if(isset($submit)){

    global $user_ID;

    $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => $postTitle,
        'post_content' => $post,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_author' => $user_ID,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_category' => array(0)
    );

    wp_insert_post($new_post);

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
<form action="" method="post">
<table border="1" width="200">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="post_title">Post Title</label></td>
    <td><input name="post_title" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="post">Post</label></td>
    <td><input name="post" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I found this at [Themeforest](http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/wordpress-user-post-without-login/26049?page=1#241206) it's working fine,
you can do a lot of things with this, you have to add some extra code to check if a user is logged in or whatever you want to do,

In the other hand you have to search in the WordPress plugins repo to find out some great plugins,
[Search for "frontend"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/frontend)

hope it helps

Comment: @Philip: I tried this but get the following error: Parse error: parse error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in /home/www/web21/html/tornfraua/wp-admin/custom-post-new.php on line 10

Comment: @Roflcoptr, remove the close '?>' from line 10 and it will be fine!

Comment: Is there any way to Integrate the category drop-down list?

Comment: @Towfiq - Yes, but i can't write at the comments the code, you have to make a new question!

Comment: @Philip can you use http://pastebin.com/

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to this — only thing is, that I'm using a Custom Post Type and a custom taxonomy.
I can't get the category thing to save the data — everything else saves in the database just fine.
Anyone has a answer or just a guess to what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Haha, that's my tutorial that failed badly. Sorry bout that, it was something I wrote because I never had the 404 issue everyone else had with it.

The frontend post forms I use most times open up in a modal window, for example, the post forms I made for http://wphonors.com are loaded in the thickbox popup thing, which I believe is why I never had an issue with this. I was able to do anything I wanted with my forms, ajax submit, on submit redirect to submitted posts, or just show a message and go to a random page.

My bad on failing with that tutorial, I had good intentions :)

Maybe try loading them using thickbox, it's really very simple to do. I'm still working on a follow up tutorial to redeem that failed on, but it's been hard to make it work the way most people would be likely to implement it in their sites.