# How to allow visitors to enter custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I wanted to use a custom post type to create a "share your story" type of feature. People would fill in the text boxes and "share their story". This would then be automatically posted on to a stories page.

But I can't figure out how to have the data entry page be a decent looking page instead of one of the admin pages, i.e. I want the data input screen to be on the front end instead of the back end.

Does anyone have any examples/tutorials on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to give your visitors or members the ability to post a story/post from the front-end,

take a look at those answers here:
[Front-End Post Submission](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5979/fron-end-post-submission/6043#6043)
[WP insert post PHP function and Custom Fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/wp-insert-post-php-function-and-custom-fields/8600#8600)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this example http://voodoopress.com/2011/03/review-of-posting-from-front-end-form/

Then you only have to set your post type and use taxonomies if you like. You can set the post status to 'pending' so you must aprove the post before publishing.

I recomend you to use the code but checking if user is logged.

My modified code: http://pastebin.com/kwTYaqyT

Comment: Aside from your paste is not working (seems to have expired), we expect knowledge to be kept on the site. Please always include all info in your answer, instead of external sources.