# How to display magic field's custom write panel in wordpress theme?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, wp-admin, plugin-magic-fields

So here is the thing.

I'm creating a site. A user can register in my site and post articles. The thing is I don't want separate admin area to post articles. I want to integrate everything in my theme. So the user don't need to go to wp-admin to create posts.

I'm using magic fields plugin. I created a custom write panel. Now my only problem is i don't know what shortcode or hook i should use to display that custom write panel in my theme. I mean i want the whole write panel in my theme.  Here is a sample snapshot of custom write panel.

[image]

I want to display the whole custom panel in my frontend. So logged in users can submit articles from that page. I hope you guys get what i mean. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it won't work quite like that.

There are plugins that enable posting from the front end, such as [TDO Mini Forms](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/).

Or [see this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13430/front-end-post-submit-form/14019#14019) for creating a form and code yourself.