# Is there a way of posting or inserting content directly to the database (without entering the wp-admin)?

Tags: posts

Is there a way of for instance, insert a post and assign a category to it, without accessing Wordpress' back-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes @janoChen, you can use wp_insert_post,

take a look at this answers:

[WP insert post PHP function and Custom Fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/wp-insert-post-php-function-and-custom-fields/8600#8600)
[Front-End Post Submission](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5979/fron-end-post-submission/6043#6043)