# Can't assign another category other than Uncategorized int he following front end post submission form?

Tags: posts, categories, forms

I'm using this front end post submission form that I took from [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5979/front-end-post-submission) question:

```
<?php 

$postTitle = $_POST['post_title'];
$post = $_POST['post'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$category = $_POST['cat'];

if(isset($submit)){

    global $user_ID;

    $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => $postTitle,
        'post_content' => $post,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_author' => $user_ID,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_category' => $category
    );

    wp_insert_post($new_post);

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
<form action="" method="post">
<table border="1" width="200">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="post_title">Post Title</label></td>
    <td><input name="post_title" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="post">Post</label></td>
    <td><input name="post" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="post_category">Category</label></td>
    <td><?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_count=1&hierarchical=1&hide_empty=0'); ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, I'm trying to add the category field:

Top of the file:

```
$category = $_POST['cat'];
```

The `$post` array:

```
 'post_category' => $category
```

Form part:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_count=1&hierarchical=1&hide_empty=0'); ?>
```

The HTML for the drop down menu displays but when I select another category say, Jobs, the post is published as Uncategorized.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the Codex:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post#Categories)

> Categories need to be passed as an **array of integers** that match the category IDs in the database. This is the case even where only one category is assigned to the post.

Currently you giving it a string of the category ID.

Try:

```
$category = array(intval($_POST['cat']));
```