# How do I rename the wp-admin folder with the admin_url filter?

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, rewrite-rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I rename the wp-admin folder?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106/can-i-rename-the-wp-admin-folder)

I have applied some mod_rewrite rules to redirect `/wp-admin` to `/my-admin` - based on [this tutorial](http://www.phpmagicbook.com/hide-wordpress-wp-admin-login-page/).

I also changed the admin url internally by hooking into `admin_url` and replacing the `/wp-admin` string:

```
add_filter('admin_url', 'my_admin_url');
function my_admin_url($path)
{
   return str_replace('wp-admin', 'my-admin', $path);
}
```

**Update #1**
In order to not break those (about 200) code parts with hardcoded `/wp-admin`, I search&replace all relevant `$_SERVER` attributes with `/wp-admin` early in my `functions.php`. This works so far.

**Update #2**
Rewriting the `$_SERVER` attributes in `functions.php` is too late for a correct setup of `$current_screen`, which might break code parts depending on it. The setup eventually happens in `wp-includes/vars.php` (by setting the global variable `$pagenow`), which is too early to hook into by plugins.

I fixed this issue by moving `$_SERVER` rewrites to `wp-config.php` - which is early enough. :)

---

#### Problems with approach described above ↑

The approach above might not work for conditions which compare `admin_url()` to one of the `$_SERVER` attributes (first one points to `/my-admin`, second one to `/wp-admin`). However, first tests indicate that none of such conditions are present in the WP core code.

Does anybody see other problems with this approach?

Comment: `$current_screen` just sums up some globals during `admin-header.php` and earlier. So if this one is wrong, then it's just an indicator that stuff didn't work out. **I encourage you to change your question title:** »_How do I change the wp-admin directory name with the admin_url filter?_«. Then just add your function on top and leave the rest as it is. This makes the Q more broad in scope and will maybe bring up better debug backtracing and possibly also other solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your help! In fact, if I use `set_current_screen()` manually for debugging, things get better! But still no posts/pages are displayed, so I think I have to dig deeper into the screen functionality, if it is based on requested pages. Any suggestions where to look for?

Comment: You **don't** have to modify the current screen object contents. If you "dig deeper", then you're hiding away the problem for yourself and just fill the gap that you encountered with dublicated code. This is just the first step to rebuilding WP - for no reason. You'll have to find out, what exactly the problem is. So far, I guess it's all those places where `wp-admin` is hard coded into core. I'd start doing a cross file search for this and list the results here.

Comment: I have to disagree here. First, I have no intention of rebuilding WP or duplicating code. I am only using regular filters and action hooks. Second, how could you possibly hook into stuff like `apply_filters("manage_{$screen->id}_sortable_columns",$this->get_sortable_columns());`, without a valid screen object? Anyway, I agree that hardcoded `/wp-admin` is the problem (which I already solved, please see update above). By "digging deeper" I meant to hook into the right spot and correct the root cause for the invalid `$current_screen` object. This is still an open issue, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The `$current_screen` object is built by code. No need to built that yourself - not even for custom screens as, like written ↑ above, you have admin-header.php and such, that do that for you. I already posted your Q on wp-hackers list, but so far I guess the only way is to add additional rules to your `.htaccess` file. With the caveat, that some stuff still won't work. I guess this one's currently is a `WON'TFIX`, but let's wait and see if the core contributers have to add anything to your Q. [BTW: I found this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106/can-i-rename-the-wp-admin-folder)

Comment: I had no intention of building the `$current_screen` object by myself, I just wanted to correct the setup procedure - which is necessary due to the rewritten request urls. And I finally succeeded, see above. :) What do you think about this solution? Any bugs likely to occur? Do you see conflicts with the WP plugin programming paradigms?

Comment: Please see the answer from [Dion Hulse on wp-hackers](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!topic/wp-hackers/yyApdV_8Npk).