# How to build custom WP admin with custom URLs

Tags: customization, admin, wp-admin, url-rewriting, urls

I would like to create a custom WP admin area, that uses custom URLs to navigate thought it and have a custom generated HTML.

A member will be able to login via a custom URL, for example: mysite.com/dashaboard or my.mysite.com When logged in a member will be able to see custom admin area where she/he can create pages, view/edit profile and so forth.

I know this is doable in WP. However, I can't find anything that would explain the whole process well and take me through the steps in more detail.

Currently, I don't know at all how to start tackling this. What's the best URL structure as a subdomain or not? What other considerations should be thought about? How to seamlessly integrate login/logout/password reminder WP functionality? How to integrate WP page and post creation (I'm guessing via URL masking)?

I know this is a massive task. I would hugely appreciate if someone could explain a general picture of how to achieve this and what should be considered and help me to go through it step by step. Maybe someon can give me some pointers/links to research first, then I will get back to for help for the next step and so on.

This might be a massive task for the stackexchange, perhaps someone will consider becoming my programming mentor and we can communicate via email/skype.

I really much want to learn this. Please help me :) I'm ready to invest time into research and learning, but I need guidelines and mentoring.

What do you guys think? Any ideas and pointers are much appreciated.

Thank you, Dasha

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has some pretty solid documentation for this. What you are asking for will require that you learn a good bit of programming.

Check out here for basic plugin development information: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

This page has specific information about making your own administration panels:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus

If this is something you are passionate about I would consider looking around at local community colleges for courses in web programming. There are also numerous classes/guides available online if you learn well that way.

Answer (score 1):

I've **never** seen any working method to do this. AFAIK, the consensus among developers is that masking/re-branding `wp-admin` URL is not feasible. *The* Question that deals with this here at WPSE is: [Can I rename the wp-admin folder?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/106/12615) Answer: no.

A bit more of research with other attempts:

- **[Rename the wp-admin directory](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/Rename-the-wp-admin-directory-td866.html)**: discussion at [wp-hackers] mailing list, prompted by our fellow [@kaiser](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/385/kaiser).
- **[How do I rename the wp-admin folder with the admin_url filter?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/43560/12615)**: this Q&A is linked on kaiser's hacker report. This is the only place where I saw the filter hook `admin_url` mentioned as a tool for this task.
- [**Debranding wp-admin with htaccess**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10318245/1287812): at Stack Overflow, *sandip patil* Answer seems interesting but there's no feedback about it working or not.
- [**Use htaccess to mask wp-admin folder**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15849031/1287812): at SO, zero feedback.
- [**How do I obscure my Wordpress install via htaccess?**](https://serverfault.com/q/281881/128311): completely failed attempt at Server Fault. I suggest stop reading the accepted answer at bullet point #6.
- **[Steps to Take to Hide the Fact a Site is Using WordPress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1507/12615)**: here at WPSE, covers mostly the front-end side. My answer contains a working (front-end) method.

As for the Login URLs, it's easy because it runs on the root file `wp-login.php` and there are plenty of filter hooks.
For that, I use [@bainternet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2487/bainternet)'s plugin [WordPress Easy Login URL with no htaccess](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/wordpress-easy-login-url-with-no-htaccess).