# Change admin URL for Wordpress 4.4.2

Tags: admin, wp-admin

I need the admin URL `wp-admin/` to be something else. This is not for security. It only personal preference.

I've tried many plugins and guide which doesn't seems to work for Wordpress 4.4.2:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/147881/81766

https://wordpress.org/plugins/protect-wp-admin/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/goodbye-wp-admin/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-admin-url/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-login/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/hc-custom-wp-admin-url/

The guide on first line above do redirect to correct location after login, but showing white screen instead of admin contents.

Some of the plugins also gave similar result, while the rest just give no difference.

Comment: So what in your opinion make it a non duplicate of the first link you pointed to? the general answer there is that it is not possible.... you could have commented on the answer of the guy saying it works for him. (I think it is possible, but this is too complex and then some plugins might break)

Comment: That question posted 6 years ago, and that answer I pointed was posted 2 years ago. That answer works for Wordpress on that time and not works for Wordpress 4.4.2. I asked for version 4.4.2 as stated on question.

Comment: If you want this question deleted because of duplicate, I need the person who asked that question to change his question to be "Can I rename the wp-admin folder for Wordpress 4.4.2?"

Comment: Sometime it feels like people are convinced this is a site for lawyers instead of web developer and start to argue about some imagery fine print. If you think it is not a duplicate you should state why, just because it is a new version is a very stupid reason, as you will probably come again in two weeks when 4.5 will be released and ask the same again, something that makes some sense for lawyers but no sense to software developers. If you have an avidance something was changed please spell it out.