# How rename wp-content and wp-admin folders correctly

Tags: php, filters, wp-admin, wp-config

I've readed that using some constant defined into the wp-config.php file is possible to use a  custom folder instead of the default wp-content. The same thing if I've understood can be applied also to [wp-admin folder](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106/can-i-rename-the-wp-admin-folder). The constant are the following

```php
//Rename wp-content folder
define ('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'Folder_Name');

//Define new directory path
define ('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
 
//Define new directory URL
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_SITEURL . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
```

I'm not sure if this will cause problem for wp-content folder, for the wp-admin this seems not work. Is this possible or I need to leave the things as is?

Comment: you've misunderstood the question you linked to, `wp-admin` cannot be renamed, the accepted answer says it is not possible

Answer (score 3):

To rename the wp-content and wp-admin folders in WordPress, you can use constants defined in the wp-config.php file. The following constants can be used to rename wp-content folder:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'Folder_Name');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
```

For wp-admin folder, renaming it using constants is not recommended as it may cause issues with WordPress core files. It is recommended to leave the wp-admin folder as is.

Comment: I'm creating an internal system that is also exposed to internet, this is why I want to make this changes, it will be more difficult for an attackers to detect a wp installation

Comment: You can make it as you want.

Comment: for the wp-content there is no problem, I have problems only with wp-admin that will be not work also if I try using an .htaccess rewrite rule

Comment: renaming `wp-admin` is not just "not recommended", it's not possible, there are no constants! WP core, plugins, JS, themes, and the admin area itself all hardcode `wp-admin`, which always has the name `wp-admin` and always in a particular place relative to the WP install. Changing it would require a hard fork of WordPress and all the plugins and themes in use. The best you can hope for is to implement your own admin area, redirect visitors to WP Admin to other places, and block it at a server level, but even then you need certain files to be available for things like admin AJAX or post to work